# Error while decoding base64 string to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, base64, string-decoding

[image]I am trying to decode base64 String to `UIImage` in **Swift 4.2**. I have tried almost every solution on **stackoverflow** but it's not working.

I have tried converting the `string` with `NSData`, it didn't work. Now I am converting the `string` to `Data` and afterwards to `image` but it's giving this error. (Type of expression is ambiguous without more context)

```
let encodedImageData = "gggg"
    //let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedImageData, 
    options: .)

    //let imageData = NSData(base64Encoded: encodedImageData, 
     options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    //let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

    //Trying to get this to work.
    if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded:encodedImageData, 
     options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
        let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
    }
```

It will be much appreciated, if anyone could point out what i am doing wrong. or give me solution. i have tried most of the solution anyways.
Thank you

Comment: The code of the `if let` expression is correct. The error must be somewhere else. Basically don't use `NS...` classes in Swift at all if there is a native equivalent.

Comment: What are the swift equivalent classes. I have used DATA later on?

Comment: Exactly, the equivalents are the structs with the same name but without NS prefix

Comment: But it isn't working either.

Comment: do you have a code snippet to decode base64 string to UIImage in Swift 4.2

Comment: I tried your code, it **does** work. If the optional binding fails then the passed string is not correctly base64 encoded (for example `gggg` will never work). But once again after reading the error message I suppose that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, i know "gggg" is not a valid base64. But the thing is. it shows a syntax error, at my side. the code dosen't even complies

Comment: if let decodedData = NSData.init(base64Encoded: kitchen.picture!, options: []) {
                    let data = decodedData.base64EncodedData(options: [])
                    cell.kitchenImage.image = UIImage.init(data: data )
                    print( "Dcoded image: ", cell.kitchenImage.image)
                }

Comment: ^ this code i wrote. it does not give any error. but it dosen't convert the string to UIImage

Comment: What is `kitchen.picture`?

Comment: oh, it's just a base64 String

Comment: If it's really a (non-optional) base64 string then the error message `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context)` must not appear. And please stop using `NSData`

Comment: When using data it gives me(Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Data' with an argument list of type '(base64Encoded: String, options: [Any])'). That is why i am using NSData. Data don't even have a base64Encoded inializer

Comment: i have added a pic see

Comment: ??? The proper initializer (`Data(base64Encoded:options:`) is in the code but the `options` type is not `[Any]`. I tried literally the code in the question. It compiles and it works (if `encodedImageData` is a valid base64 string)

Comment: Damn, i made a new project, which was on swift 4. and code works fine.

Comment: Thanks Alot @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally found the problem. Data class was not finding the base64Encoded inializer, and xcode was getting confused. As Data class is in the Foundation Framework. so what i did was.

```
  if let decodedImage =  Foundation.Data(base64Encoded: 
  "your base64 String", options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters){
            let image = UIImage(data: decodedImage)
   }
```

i directly referred it to the Foundation Framework, and it's working like a chram.

Comment: As I said: *the error is somewhere else*. You are strongly discouraged from naming a custom class or struct `Data` or other names of the system frameworks. This avoids ambiguity errors like that.

Comment: I sure , will not forget this. it took me 9 hourse to debug this. Anyways thanks alot mate. :D